# How do I force eclipse to show xml layouts and styles as text?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, android-xml

I recently moved up to Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) with ADT 20.0.3.

If I view a layout or a style from an old project Eclipse just shows me its appropriate controls-based editor. I want to edit the syntax-highlighted xml text. I don't see a way to switch the plugin's editor to this mode although it will fallback to it for a layout it chokes on and can't give a WYSIWYG display for.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**:
This problem turned out to be a side effect of my [recent adventures in themeing Eclipse 4.2](http://hoogli.com/blogs/android/index.html#Light_on_Dark_Eclipse_4.2_%28Juno%29_Themes). Using the **Dark Juno** theme, the buttons for switching between text and wysiwyg views at the bottom of the editor disappeared entirely (not just the wrong colours, zero screen area). Switching back to the default theme solves the issue.

For the benefit of the Dark Juno author, I noticed Eclipse outputting this on the command line (my ellipses):

```
~$ eclipse
Failed to find defStyle: listViewStyle
...
Failed to find defStyle: textViewStyle
...
Failed to find defStyle: buttonStyle
...
```

***EDIT 2***:
This turns out to be a known issue with Dark Juno: https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes/issues/11

Does anyone know of a way to make the switch to text without using the buttons that I cannot see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Alt+PgDn to switch through the inner tabs.

But we need a permanent solution from Dark Juno. Hope to get a patch soon.

Till then use Alt+PgDn.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually better than a widget to click.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply choose the tab which shows the raw code instead of the controls from the bottom bar:

[image]

Clicking on strings.xml will bring up the syntax highlighted editor, and you can do this for all XMl files.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, that is what I was using on Eclipse 3.x with an older ADT. With my new combo of Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and ADT 20.0.3, I don't see it anymore.

Comment: I'm using eclipse 3.6 with the latest ADT, and I've always had it. Glad it's working now

Answer (score 2):

If you use Eclipse on Mac OS X you can use the following key combination ⌥⇟ to switch between sub-tabs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: XML editor] Like this, with XML editor, or text editor, if you like that more.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I had found that but it opens a bizarre tree-view structured editor, not a simple syntax-highlighted text editor.

Comment: Ok, see my edit to the question above. The buttons to swtch between the tree-view and text were missing. All solved now. Thaks again.

Answer (score 0):

It still seems to be not fixed. On OS X the shortcut is Fn + Option + Up/Down(effectively Alt + PageUp/PageDown on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the bug of Dark Juno,removing the line:

```
swt-tab-renderer: url(bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering);
```

from the **CTabFolder** element in “**com.github.eclipsecolortheme.themes/themes/css/juno.css**” .

Reference:
https://github.com/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes/issues/11#issuecomment-11439747