# When I opened the layout file in eclipse with Android common XML editor,there is only one view mode shown to me

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

The option bar at the bottom doesn't exist.

I can only use the graphical layout view mode,unless I select the xml file to open with other xml editor.

So,how can I fix that?

Thanks！

**update:**

In fact, I can use the hot key "shift+alt+f7" to switch the view mode between graphical layout and xml editor, while there is no option bar at the bottom.

**update2:**

Finally,I find the cause of the problem.
This problem turned out to be a side effect of the Dark Juno theme.

reference:
[How do I force eclipse to show xml layouts and styles as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534818/how-do-i-force-eclipse-to-show-xml-layouts-and-styles-as-text)

Comment: Build and restart eclipse ,might work.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Thanks for answering.I have tried everything I can to fix it,including restarting eclipse and updating ADT plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any of the layout files in the package explorer(on the left),  right click -> Open With -> Android Layout Editor

Comment: There is not any options named "Android Layout Editor" under the "open with".